# how to modify weblogic-application.xml in Oracle 12c

Tags: migration, weblogic

After migrating to JDEV 12c, I am facing such issue: **java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This DocumentBuilder, "oracle.xml.jaxp.JXDocumentBuilder", does not support the reset functionality**

I found in the deployed folder for my application: **C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.2.42.161008.1648\o.j2ee\drs\myApp\META-INF**, there's a "weblogic-application.xml" file which is not existing in my application code base at all. Everytime when I start the application, this file seems generated automatically.

By comparing this "weblogic-application.xml" between 12c and 11g, it shows that in 12c, there's an extra  element:

```
<xml>
    <parser-factory>
      <saxparser-factory>oracle.xml.jaxp.JXSAXParserFactory</saxparser-factory>
      <document-builder-factory>oracle.xml.jaxp.JXDocumentBuilderFactory</document-builder-factory>
      <transformer-factory>oracle.xml.jaxp.JXSAXTransformerFactory</transformer-factory>
    </parser-factory>
  </xml>
```

This  element is not appearing in 11g's copy at all. I am suspecting this could be the cause of the error.

So here's my question: how can I control this "weblogic-application.xml"? I want to try to remove this  element. But don't know how to achieve that since this file doesn't exist in my application code base.

Thanks,

Shawn

P.S.
I do find a couple of "weblogic-application.xml" in my application, but none of them has that  element. Where comes this  element?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my case, it turns out that this jar file in 12c, xmlparserv2.jar, has been changed so that the reset() method in "oracle.xml.jaxp.JXDocumentBuilder" is not implemented at all, hence throws out that UnsupportedOperationException exception. For my application, it should pick the one from this jar file: xercesImpl.jar.

So the solution is to remove the xmlparserv2.jar from the ear file so that the class from xercesImpl.jar will be picked up.